# Custom submodules in pytorch / libtorch C++

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

Full disclosure, I asked this same question on the PyTorch forums about a few days ago and got no reply, so this is technically a repost, but I believe it's still a good question, because I've been unable to find an answer anywhere online. Here goes:

**Can you show an example of using register_module with a custom module?**
The only examples I’ve found online are registering linear layers or convolutional layers as the submodules.

I tried to write my own module and register it with another module and I couldn’t get it to work.
My IDE is telling me `no instance of overloaded function "MyModel::register_module" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (const char [14], TreeEmbedding)`

(TreeEmbedding is the name of another struct I made which extends torch::nn::Module.)

Am I missing something? An example of this would be very helpful.

Edit: Additional context follows below.

I have a header file "model.h" which contains the following:

```cpp
struct TreeEmbedding : torch::nn::Module {
    TreeEmbedding();
    torch::Tensor forward(Graph tree);
};

struct MyModel : torch::nn::Module{
    size_t embeddingSize;
    TreeEmbedding treeEmbedding;

    MyModel(size_t embeddingSize=10);
    torch::Tensor forward(std::vector<Graph> clauses, std::vector<Graph> contexts);
};
```

I also have a cpp file "model.cpp" which contains the following:

```cpp
MyModel::MyModel(size_t embeddingSize) :
    embeddingSize(embeddingSize)
{
    treeEmbedding = register_module("treeEmbedding", TreeEmbedding{});
}
```

This setup still has the same error as above. The code in the documentation does work (using built-in components like linear layers), but using a custom module does not. After tracking down torch::nn::Linear, it looks as though that is a `ModuleHolder` (Whatever that is...)

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: What is your PyTorch version? According to [documentation](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/structtorch_1_1jit_1_1_module.html#_CPPv4N5torch3jit6Module15register_moduleERKNSt6stringERK6Module) you should be able to `register_module("tree_embedding", tree_embedding)` provided the second argument subclasses `torch::nn::Module` as is correctly instantiated. Doesn't `register_module("tree_embedding", TreeEmbedding{neccessary, arguments})` work? Did you create `private` members in your class of `TreeEmbedding` type?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of pytorch exactly I have, but I downloaded the latest version in the last month or so, so I'd think it'd be relatively new. ```register_module("tree_embedding", TreeEmbedding{neccessary, arguments})``` did not work for me. I'm not sure if you're asking if my outer module has a private instance of type TreeEmbedding, or if you're asking if my TreeEmbedding has private members inside it...but either way the answer is no. I do have a public member of type TreeEmbedding inside of my outer module.

Comment: @JackKeown PyTorch `1.5.0` with stable C++ API was released on 21.04.2020 so you may want to redownload `libtorch` as it's a major change. By `{}` I mean object construction using C++'s uniform initialization with arguments required by your `constructor` so I don't mean either. From what I see in your answer, with `1.5.0` you may check whether `treeEmbedding = register_module("treeEmbedding", TreeEmbedding{})` as shown in [PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/frontend.html#end-to-end-example) (provided you inherit from `torch::nn::Module` as mentioned previously) works.

Comment: Also, your outer module should have a public member of type `TreeEmbedding` named `treeEmbedding`, once again check how it's done in the aforementioned tutorial for `Linear` layers. And if you could post code of `TreeEmbedding` and your outer module into which you are trying to register `TreeEmbedding` it would be helpful.

Comment: As you can see in my edited question, I have tried all of these things. I even just now downloaded the latest version using ```wget https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/nightly/cpu/libtorch-shared-with-deps-latest.zip``` from the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will accept a better answer if anyone can provide more details, but just in case anyone's wondering, I thought I would put up the little information I was able to find:

register_module takes in a string as its first argument and its second argument can either be a ModuleHolder (I don't know what this is...) or alternatively it can be a shared_ptr to your module. So here's my example:

```
treeEmbedding = register_module<TreeEmbedding>("treeEmbedding", make_shared<TreeEmbedding>());
```

This seemed to work for me so far.